# Python inheritance: Create parent class object from child class

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a set of classes where a child is derived from a parent. 
What I am trying to achieve is to create an object of the parent class that gets all its values from an object of the child class.
The only way I found is this:

```py
from copy import deepcopy
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.val = value

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, val=8):
         super(Child, self).__init__(val)
         chval=5
par=Parent(3)
ch=Child()
parent= Parent(4)
parent.__dict__ = deepcopy(super(Child, ch).__dict__)
print(parent.val)
print(type(par), type(ch), type(parent))
```

The output is indeed

```
8
(<class '__main__.Parent'>, <class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>)
```

but I am not sure whether this is a good, pythonesque and risk-free method of doing this

Comment: The problem isn't with the approach, but with the OOP design that the child object inherits the parent class' attributes & methods and not the other way around.

Comment: I have never heard of creating a parent class from a child class and I guess it is not possible. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That is not how OOP is supposed (nor designed) to work.

Comment: The Child is-a Parent so the object you want to create is actually there - what is your use case (plus this `chval` does not do anything)

Comment: The use case is rather complicated; basically I have an object class that is a node in a tree which is derived from some single-object class and I want to create a new node that shares all values of the single-object class but not the nodes attributes.

Comment: A similar example would be a geometry class, where I have a basic figure object that stores the line width, color, fill color, etc., and derived classes like rectangle, circle. How would I create a circle with the the basic figure properties of a rectangle?

Comment: " I want to create a new node that shares all values of the single-object class but not the nodes attributes." => what difference do you see between values and attributes ??? What you're asking for seems a bit weird, so you should probably post a more concrete example based on a simplified version of your real use case.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: How would I create a `Circle` with the the basic `Figure` properties of a `Rectangle`?
>   """

You can do this by implementing a method `new_from` in the Base `class Figure`.
For example:

```
class Figure:
    def __init__(self, p):
        self.properties = p

    @classmethod
    def new_from(cls, obj):
        if issubclass(obj.__class__, Figure):
            _new = cls(obj.properties)
            return _new
        else:
            raise TypeError('Expected subclass of <class Figure>, got {}.'\
                                .format(type(obj)))

    def __repr__(self):
      return "<class '{}' properties:{}"\
                .format(self.__class__.__name__, self.properties)

class Rectangle(Figure):
    pass    

class Circle(Figure):
    pass

r1 = Rectangle({'test': 'r1.property'})
r2 = Rectangle.new_from(r1)
c1 = Circle({'test': 'c1.property'})
c2 = Circle.new_from(r1)

for obj in [r1, r2, c1, c2]:
    print(obj)  # '{}\n{}'.format(obj, obj.__dict__))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> <class 'Rectangle' properties:{'test': 'r1.property'}
> <class 'Rectangle' properties:{'test': 'r1.property'}
> <class 'Circle' properties:{'test': 'c1.property'}
> <class 'Circle' properties:{'test': 'r1.property'}
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.6***

Comment: Late to the question, but what about when you can't add new methods to base class?

Comment: @MorJ ***"what about when you can't add new methods to base class"***: Means you want to extend `Figure` then do `class MyFigure(Figure)` and use this afterwards, e.g. `Rectangle(MyFigure):`